# 3D реконструкция с двух камер с помощью opencv

Tags: python, opencv

Задача классическая - получение 3d координат по двум изображениям.
Решаю  помощью OpenCV.
Последовательность действий такая (очевидные действия пропускаю):

1) Ищем на изображениях imagepoints с помощью findChessboardCorners.

```
    ret0, corners0 = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray0, (cols,rows),None)
    ret1, corners1 = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray1, (cols,rows),None)
```

Результат:
[image: первая камера]
[image: вторая камера]
2) Калибруем камеры с помощью

```
    ret0, mtx0, dist0, rvecs0, tvecs0 = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints0, imgpoints0, gray0.shape[::-1],None,None)
    ret1, mtx1, dist1, rvecs1, tvecs1 = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints1, imgpoints1, gray0.shape[::-1],None,None)
```

3) Получаем информацию о векторах поворота R и трансляции T и матрицы проекции P0 и P1:

```
retval, cameraMatrix1, distCoeffs1, cameraMatrix2, distCoeffs2, R, T, E, F = cv2.stereoCalibrate(
    objpoints0, 
    imgpoints0, 
    imgpoints1, 
    mtx0, 
    dist0, 
    mtx1, 
    dist1,
    (1280,720,), 
)

R0, R1, P0, P1, Q, validPixROI0, validPixROI1 = cv2.stereoRectify(
    cameraMatrix1, 
    distCoeffs1, 
    cameraMatrix2, 
    distCoeffs2, 
    (1280, 720,), 
    R, 
    T, 
    None,
    None,
    None, 
    None
)
```

4) Делаем триангуляцию:

```
points = np.array([
    [[381,198],[433,418]],
    [[393,231],[435,453]],
    [[415,225],[465,454]],
    [[406,195],[169,420]]
])


for p in points:
    print(p)
    s = np.array(cv2.triangulatePoints(P0, P1, 
                              p[0], 
                              p[1])).T


    print(s)
```

Точки в массиве `points` соответствуют углам одной клетки, то есть в теории мы должны получить углы квадрата. Но почему-то для каждой точки значения конечных координат получаются одинаковые. Я с OpenCV, да и вообще с компьютерным зрением разбираюсь только пятый день, и хотелось бы разобраться, где я ошибаюсь.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ оказался прост: необходимо явно задать тип значений в массиве `points` как `np.float32` и тогда все считается корректно:

```
points = np.array([
    [[381,198],[433,418]],
    [[393,231],[435,453]],
    [[415,225],[465,454]],
    [[406,195],[169,420]]
], dtype=np.float32)
```